# Windows to ubuntu-server samba share almost double as fast as ubuntu or mac os x to samba share

Tags: networking, server, samba, file-sharing, windows-10

I have recently build my second home server. And it is working great the only weird thing that i would like to solve is that my Samba transfer speed from Windows 10 to my server is mostly around 100mbps and on the same computer with ubuntu i get around 60mbps. With my macbook i also get around 60mbps. All of this is with a gigabit network setup. (No wireless)
I have tried multiple guides to speed up my samba share but they don't seem to improve anything.
I'm running ubuntu server 14.04.02 lts

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=173211
http://www.eggplant.pro/blog/faster-samba-smb-cifs-share-performance/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something to bear in mind is that Samba is designed for communication between Windows and Linux machines, so should work faster than the other two.  For filesharing between Linux machines [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) is the correct protocol to use.

The Ubuntu help page for NFS can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo).

Comment: That worked great! Thanks, i get around 100mbps with the nfs share witch is as good as the samba share with windows.